# On Google Sheets, how do I 'attach' the value of a cell to the value of the cell on the left?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with 3 columns, say A, B and C, though only column C is editable by the user.

Column A contains values all from another sheet - the number of values in this column can change as values are deleted or added to the other sheet (EDIT: new values can be added to any part of the other sheet, not just the bottom).
Column B is a uniquely sorted list of the values of Column A.
Column C is currently just a normal column that takes values from the user.

When a user enters a value in a Column C cell, they do so based on the cell to the left (in column B). However, as the values in the other sheet can change, values in column B can be deleted or move up or down a row, or new values can appear anywhere in this column B.

Somehow, when the user puts "bar" into a cell in column C on row X and the value of column B on row X is "foo", then rather than "bar" always just staying in cell CX: 1) when "foo" changes it's row to row Y (because another value has been added to or removed from column B, or the first letters of the value in BX have been changed), "bar" should also move to row Y 2) if "foo" is completely removed from column B, "bar" should also be removed from column C 3) new values in column B should have blank column C cells to the right of them.

Eg say the table looks like this

```
B:           C:
apple        Rsdne fwe
banana       Fg fdsg gse
grape        Awtoi fje
lime         Wpe fjweo
orange       Jbob
```

If on the other sheet: a new value "kiwi" is added, "orange" is changed to "clementine" and "bananas" is removed, after all this the table should then look like this:

```
B:           C:
apple        Rsdne fwe
clementine   Jbob
grape        Awtoi fje
kiwi
lime         Wpe fjweo
```

Is this / any of this possible? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 2):

Data entry should happen in a fixed table and not into a moving structure. Changing the association of a data entry row to a different parameter is simply bad data architecture.  There isn't a simple formula solution to counter that.

My advice is to step back and determine what you want to achieve, then design a process that is fit for that purpose.

Creating a unique list of values from a hidden column is a reporting technique. Then this report is getting mixed with data entry. These two things, i.e. data entry and reporting should never happen on the same sheet.

Create a sheet that has all the possible unique values in a constant data entry table. Let the user enter their values into that DataEntry Table. New values can be added to the bottom of the table. If Orange is changed to Clementine, don't delete the row for Orange, just leave it and add a new row for Clementine.

Then you can create a report that takes the duplicates from your initial first sheet, creates a list of unique values and then uses lookups formulas to pull the user entries from the DataEntry table.

Comment: Thanks teylyn, appreciate your answer.

Comment: Problem is these: "Create a sheet that has all the possible values" can't as values can be any sentence, and "New values can be added to the bottom of the table" part of why this is useful is, the new values are entered onto another sheet but they could be entered anywhere on there depending on where on that sheet they relate to, those values are pulled into Column A of this sheet but since they aren't on the bottom of the other sheet they wouldn't come into the bottom of column A so even without column B sorting and filtering the new values would go into the middle. Fixed table may not work?

Comment: Column A doesn't actually have to be a hidden column at all, so would that make it less of a reporting technique? (Maybe what I'm trying to do is not possible, but theoretically I don't see a reason why it's wrong for a value to be fixed to the value of the cell next to it, rather than its location). Anyway, since I can do most of the suggestions in your answer, all I'm asking for now really is that when there's a new value in the other sheet which gets added to the middle of a column in this sheet, a whole new row is created in for that value. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: (We have a one sheet solution but this would be nicer)